# contentBinding between Ember.ArrayController and Ember.View [ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js]

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I bind my ArrayController.content to a View, in order to draw a canvas depending on the Object within my ArrayController.

[jsFiddle - Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gcLft/11/)
The Binding for the values in the controller is working, but not for the content.values.

**Question 1:**
Is it a conceptual failure? I was not able to found detailed info for my problem. For ObjectController it's working, but not for ArrayController.

**Question 2:**
What is the best solution, to update the view, if the Object.values (e.q. faceColor) changes?

Html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

<h1>each</h1>
{{#each App.andonController}}
    {{view "App.AndonView"}}
    {{faceColor}} {{emotionType}}
{{/each}}   

</script>
```

The Object

```
App.Andon = Ember.Object.extend({
    emotionType: '',
    faceColor: '',
});
```

The View

I would like to draw an element within a canvas vor each Object in my ArrayController

```
App.AndonView = Ember.View.extend({

    tagName: "canvas",
    attributeBindings: ['height', 'width'],
    height: 100,
    width: 100,

    controllerBinding:'App.andonController.content',
    faceColorBinding: 'content.faceColor',
    emotionTypeBinding: 'content.emotionType',

    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.drawSmiley();        
    },

    arrayDidChange: function(){
        this.drawSmiley();
    },  

    degreesToRadians : function(degrees) {...},

    drawSmiley: function(){
        ...
        var faceColor = null;
        try {
            faceColor = this.get('faceColor');
            //alert(faceColor);         
        } catch (e) {
            alert('faceColer is empty')
        } 
        ...
    } 
});
```

The Controller

```
App.andonController = Em.ArrayController.create({

    content: [

      App.Andon.create( 
      {
        emotionType: 'happy',
        faceColor: '#00ff00'
      }), 
      App.Andon.create( 
          {
              emotionType: 'sad',
              faceColor: '#665sd'
      } 
   )],

})
```

Answer (score 3):

I would restructure this a bit to use the `itemController` functionality, which is present on `each` and on `ArrayController` directly.

First, I would change your array controller from `andonController` to `andonsController`. The plural helps make it clear that it is managing the collection of andons instead of an individual object.

I'd then make a second controller to manage the individual andon object:

```
App.AndonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()
```

Now, in your loop you can instead do

```
{{#each App.andonsController itemController="App.AndonController"}}
    {{view "App.AndonView"}}
    {{faceColor}} {{emotionType}}
{{/each}}
```

An instance of `App.AndonController` (which is now an `ObjectController`, which means it will transparently pass through to its content calls for properties, including bindings and computed properties') will be created for each item in the loop, and because the controller of the view is its context, you can don't need to prepend anything to paths, and the subView gets the `controller` as its context automatically.

I've forked your JSFiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/H2zPk/

I'm more unsure about using the `context` property in your view. This is primarily for use by templates, and using it internally can lead to violations of expectations of behaviour later on, if for instance you try including it somewhere where `context` is NOT an AndonController. I would instead bind a property like `content` (<- note the spelling change) to a known valid path for the given use, and access properties off that internal variable. (I'd also not bind the context property, I'd consider that an anti-pattern).

In general where you have a situation where you're relying on a property that gets set externally and either may NOT be set in certain cases, or may not necessarily point to an object you expect, I would avoid using it directly in your class and would instead define a binding. (I'm referring particularly to built-in properties like `controller` or `context` whose behaviour can vary. Your own properties can define reasonable defaults and be documented with known behaviour and are of course safe to use directly in the view). Not only do you avoid relying on behaviour that may not be the same in all cases (or, worse, behaviour that is considered private or internal and may change in the future), you can then replace your internal property with a computed property or just bind it anywhere you'd like, without risk of blowing up Ember *and without needing to update your references*.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success with this problem by using contextBinding.
You could change your template to something like this.

```
{{#each andon in App.andonController}}
    {{view "App.AndonView" contextBinding="andon"}}
    {{faceColor}} {{emotionType}}
{{/each}}
```

and then fetch each value in the View as

```
this.get('context.faceColor')
```

and so on.
I was able to get the happy face come in your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gcLft/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working. :) And I'm sorry, for the untidy jsFiddle. I missed to update the link.

Comment: Great! You can read more about template scopes here http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_template-scopes